# My model is non-manifold because of the eyelids

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, topology, geometry

How do I model the eyelids without non-manifold vertices from multiple faces? I want my eyelids to look solid unlike the rest of the body. Should I just convert the eyelid to squares instead of cubes, and add a solidify modifier? [image]

Comment: That looks like it's non-manifold because of duplicate vertices.  Try select all and merge by distance to see if you have extra vertices.

Comment: @MartyFouts The very close vertices make up the thickness of the eyelids. I've merged vertices already.

Comment: You should be able to get the thickness while still maintaining a manifold mesh.  Could you make a blend file with just that region of the eye and share it? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: @MartyFouts the multiple faces highlighted in orange are causing the error. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QTDBJXaoVOmq0zpACgXGE8vrh1NCKNQG/view?usp=sharing